Enabled zip64 in jar build now the main class is not found or loaded?
my build.gradle file has this
tasks.register('jobsJar', Jar) {
    zip64 = true //this was added as it would not build without
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'app.listabl.jobs.JobsKt',
                'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example'
    }
    archiveBaseName = 'jobs-listabl'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

Before adding a dependency I did not need the zip64 and the jar was built using
./gradlew jobsJar and then ran using java -jar build/libs/jobs-listabl-0.0.1.jar.
I added a dependency and had to enable the zip64.
When running now java -jar build/libs/jobs-listabl-0.0.1.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class app.listabl.jobs.JobsKt                                                                                                                                                                    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.listabl.jobs.JobsKt

I looked at the MANIFEST.MF and followed the path in the jar everything looks in place. So I dont know why is the main class not loaded or found.
